# iPhone 4s downgrade from 9.2.1 to 9.0.2

Tags: iphone, downgrade

can I downgrade my iPhone 4s iOS 9.2.1 to 9.0.2? I try using ipsw but it isn't signed at this moment. Can I create custom ipsw 9.0.2?

Its possible to downgrade my iPhone?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can only downgrade if you saved an SHSH blob from the old version while Apple was still signing it. If you don't have an SHSH blob for 9.0.2 then it's too late now, and there's no way you can downgrade.

Comment: I don t have saved shsh. But I can get it from persone who saved it?

Comment: No, it has to be saved from your specific phone in order to work with your phone -- someone else's will not work.